# How can you check if SQL command is still running? Or is it frozen/dead...?

Tags: sql, sqlite, indexing, long-running-processes

I created an index for my ginormous (250 million+ records) SQL table and it has been several hours. How can I tell if it's still going? Or if the process is frozen/dead?

If you have an answer about how to check if SQL (SQLite3) is still running in general, that'd be super. However, if you have an approach for my specific case, that's good as well. This is what I did.

`CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name(column_name);`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use some monitoring mechanism of your OS (`top`, Task Manager, etc.) to check whether the process is using CPU or disk I/O.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to check:

```
sp_who2
```

You can also use active to see active connections:

```
sp_who2 active
```